# On the distribution space ${\cal E'}(\mathbb R^n)$

Tags: distribution-theory

$${\cal D}'(\mathbb R^n) \equiv \{ {\rm continuous \ linear \ functionals } \ \ u_f(\phi): {\cal D}(\mathbb R^n) \to \mathbb C, \ \  {\rm with }\  f \in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb R^n) \ {\rm and} \ \phi \in {\cal C}^{\infty}_c (\mathbb R^n)\}$$

I'd like to write a similar definition for ${\cal E'}(\mathbb R^n)$, if it's possible.

**Attempt**.

$${\cal E}'(\mathbb R^n) \equiv \{ {\rm continuous \ linear \ functionals } \ \ v_g(\psi): {\cal E}(\mathbb R^n) \to \mathbb C, \ \  {\rm with }\  g \in {\cal C}^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n) \ {\rm and} \ \psi \in {\cal C}^{\infty} (\mathbb R^n)\}$$

Is this correct? Or better, is it equivalent to the usual definitions for $\cal E'(\mathbb R^n)?$

Comment: There are many more distributions than just those obtained by integration against locally $L^1$ functions... And certainly many more compactly-supported distributions than integration against smooth functions. Are you asking what you really intend?

Comment: Thanks... actually, I was trying to understand the following theorem: "${\cal C}^\infty_c {\rm \ is \ dense \ in \ } {\cal D'}$". How can you compare a set with its dual in the first place? So I ended questioning my understanding of $\cal E'$...

Comment: True, most topological vector spaces do not have natural imbeddings into their duals! The virtue of L. Schwartz' definition of distributions as a dual was that it immediately rigorized them... but we care a great deal about the imbedding of test functions (and others) into the space of distributions: distributions are an _extension_ of (classical) "functions".

Comment: And, it is true that the distributions obtained from (integrate-against-) test functions are dense in all distributions (with the weak dual topology, for example). And test functions are dense in the space of compactly supported distributions (with its weak dual topology, for example). There is asymmetry in the latter case: the space of smooth functions does not imbed into its own dual (the compactly-supported distributions).

Comment: When we write $C_c^\infty \subset \mathcal{D}'$ we actually mean that there is an injection $\iota : C_c^\infty \to \mathcal{D}',\ f \mapsto (\varphi \mapsto \int f(x) \, \varphi(x) \, dx)$.

Comment: That is.. not every compactly supported distribution can be obtained via a succession of compactly supported functions?

Comment: @ric.san. It depends on what you mean. What you have written in your definition is that every $u\in\mathcal{E}'$ is given by integration against a $C_c^\infty$ function. That is not true. But you can take a sequence of $C_c^\infty$ functions that converges (in the distribution sense) to $u$.

Comment: It's really complicated though.. I still can't give distributions an intuitive sense. I mean they're functionals. But at the same time "generalization of functions". They *act* on functions, so how can they be their generalization?? It's like saying that "+" generalize numbers....

Comment: Ok, but... when you say a succession "converges in the distribution sense", it means you're applying a distribution on that succession. But then it's not ${\cal C}^\infty_c$ that converges per se

Comment: Every $f \in L^1_\text{loc}$ generates a distribution $T_f : \varphi \mapsto \int f(x) \, \varphi(x) \, dx.$ This distribution is *identified* with the function. But there are also distributions that are not given in this way. This makes distributions generalizations of functions.

Comment: No, I do not apply a distribution on that succession. Every $\psi_k$ in the sequence is considered as a distribution itself: $T_{\psi_k} : \varphi \mapsto \int \psi_k(x) \, \varphi(x) \, dx$. Then the sequence of distributions, $T_{\psi_k},$ converges to a distribution.

Comment: yeah, I don't see the point in identifying functions and distributions (they're fundamentally different) but ok. Thanks for your patience, really.

Comment: Such identifications are very common. Another example is how we define rational numbers as equivalence classes of pairs of integers: $(a_1,b_1) \sim (a_2,b_2)$ if $a_1 b_2 = a_2 b_1;\ b_1,b_2\neq 0.$ Thus integers and rational numbers are quite different objects. But we can still identify integers as a subset of rational numbers: $n$ is identified with the equivalence class $[(n,1)].$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one disserves oneself by thinking that "functions" and "distributions" are fundamentally different. Yes, many formalizations would seem to make them wildly different things from each other... but the historical and on-going motivations certainly do not make them wildly different.

In particular, in practice, "distributions" appear as ("weak" or other non-pointwise...) *limits* of very nice functions, for example, test functions.

So, while uniformly-on-compacts pointwise limits of continuous functions certainly are continuous, other limits (like $L^2$, without even mentioning "distributions") of continuous functions need not be continuous.

Also, a point that only dawned on me a few years ago is that probably no physicist every really thought that the "potential" $\delta$ really had $0$ extent but infinite value... but, rather, wrote $\delta$ for an idealization of a potential with very small extent but total mass (or whatever) $1$. So the fact that this is classically mathematically impossible was not too relevant, since the manipulations were really partly a *narrative* about physical-mathematical reasoning... and possibly not at all pretending to assert anything about a *literal* $\delta$.

And, again, indeed, most topological vector spaces have no natural imbedding into their duals.

But a/the fundamental interest in the space of distributions is that the space of test functions *does* imbed in it, and is dense. Yes, this is by the identification of a test function with the integrate-against-it functional, ... which turns out to be a smart choice in practice! As opposed to thinking about functions as things that have inputs numbers and outputs numbers. Further, among distributions, the compactly-supported ones are (provably) finite linear combinations of some (finite-order) derivatives of compactly-supported continuous functions. So we've not added superfluous things, if we reeeeeally want to be confident of differentiating anything at all.

Things become a little disordered when we look at the Frechet space of smooth functions, and its dual, the compactly-supported distributions. It requires a little work to prove that the dual is indeed what it is. And the space of smooth functions does *not* imbed in that dual in any natural way. Too bad. Still, test functions *are* dense in it (imbedding by the integrate-against convention).